# Python tornado stop execution with finish()

Tags: python, runtime-error, tornado

I am relatively new to tornado and I am trying to stop execution of a method if a condition passes, otherwise it should go on to the next line of code (similar to return)

This is the part my code where I am stuck,

```
class PostMatchHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    result1 = "some sql query".execute()
    if not result1:
        response.update({'info': 'Levels Completed', 'status': settings.STATUS_200})
        self.write(response)
        self.finish()

    else:
        result1 = result1[0]
        do_something()
    self.write(response)
```

BaseRequestHandler is:

```
class BaseRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """
    Base Class for all the future classes
    Activities like logging should be done in this class.
    Allow cors request in this class
    """

    def set_default_headers(self):
        print "setting headers!!!"

    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        response = {}
        handle_error_messages..
        self.write(response)

    @staticmethod
    def extract_psycopg2_integrity_error(error):
        return error.message.split("Key")[1].replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(".")[0].replace("=", " ")

    def prepare(self):
        logging.debug(
            "[info] Class {} via {} with body {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.request.uri, self.request.body))
```

So, here if result1 is empty, then it should finish the API's execution and return. But I am getting this error `RuntimeError: Cannot write() after finish()`

How shall I stop the execution.

Comment: Once you call `finish()` the request handling is completed and it's resources (e.g. network connection) is released. So, if you call any of `write` methods after `finish`, it has nowhere to write the data - that's why it raises `RuntimeError`. Note that `finish()` finishes the request, not the coroutine, to finish a coroutine you need to either use `return` (without any arguments as of Python 2), or `raise gen.Return(None)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need "self.finish", it completes Tornado's writing of the response but it does not stop execution of your function. To stop execution of a function, add a `return` statement:

```
def get(self)
    result1 = "some sql query".execute()
    if not result1:
        response.update({'info': 'Levels Completed', 'status': settings.STATUS_200})
        self.write(response)
        return  # <-- here
    else:
        result1 = result1[0]
        do_something()
    self.write(response)
```

The other option is to indent the final line so it remains within the "else" clause:

```
def get(self):
    result1 = "some sql query".execute()
    if not result1:
        response.update({'info': 'Levels Completed', 'status': settings.STATUS_200})
        self.write(response)    
    else:
        result1 = result1[0]
        do_something()
        self.write(response)  # indented 4 more spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach, very useful when you want to force ending the request from anywhere in the code, even if it's difficult to `return` (e.g. from a helper function), is to raise the [`tornado.web.Finish`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Finish) exception.